# No overload matches this call when using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

There are several questions about this error on SO but none from anybody in a similar situation and none of the solutions I have found work so I'm going to post a specific question.

When using a Styled component inside another component and passing props to it, do I have to create a new type to pass the props through to the styled component or is there some way of using the existing styled component types?

Here is my code. It seems to be the **as=""** attribute which is giving the error above. I assume this is something to do with the fact that my component only takes the prop so it can pass it to the Styled Component as it is a feator of Styled Components.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

type Props = {
    additionalClass?: string,
    as?: string
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

    return (

        <StyledComponent as={props.as} className={props.additionalClass}>
            {props.children}
        </StyledComponent>

    )

}


export default Component


const StyledComponent = styled.div`    
    ...styles go here
`
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question, but you can always pass down your props with the `<StyledComponent {...props} />` syntax.

Comment: I was also doing that but removed it to post my minimal example here. I should have explained the problem seems to be coming from the as="" attribute because this is part of styled components.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you paste the actual error message? Can you paste the definition of StyledComponent ? Are you setting some css properties based on `as`?

Comment: Did you set up TS support according to https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript ?

Comment: No, but thatnks for pointing that page out. I think I've solved it so I'm about to post the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to pass the "as" prop to styled components and I thought it needed to be a string so I did this...

```
type Props = {
    className?: string,
    as?: string
}
```

The problem is that once you pass it to styled-components it expects it to be the name of an element. I found the answer on Github and it can be one of two different things. This works...

```
type Props = {
    className?: string,
    as?: React.ElementType | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
}
```

Comment: Do you remember where on github you found the answer?

Comment: Can't say for sure but from searching my history it seems to be this page - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28806

Answer (score 31):

You just need to validate the prop when you are creating the **styled.div**

Example

```
const Menu= styled.div<{ menuOpen: boolean }>`
  ${({ menuOpen }) => {
    if (menuOpen) {
      return 'background-color: white';
    }

    return 'background-color: black';
  }}
`;

export const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return(
    <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen}>
      whatever content
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me hours of searching

Answer (score -1):

```
type Props = {
    additionalClass?: string,
    [key: string]: any
}
```